# Fragment: Cannot get string path from onActivityResult

Tags: java, android

I am trying to attach a file to my project. But the path does not display in the text view. There is no error in the code but it seems that the path did not find. I'm newbie creating a fragment. How can I get the string path?

Below is my code:

```
public class AttachmentsFragment extends Fragment {

    private Button btncf;
    private TextView tvaf;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_attachments,container,false);

            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.M && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(),android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1001);
            }

            btncf = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_choose_files);
            tvaf = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_choose_files_placeholder);

            btncf.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    new MaterialFilePicker()
                            .withActivity(getActivity())
                            .withRequestCode(1000)
                            .withHiddenFiles(true) // Show hidden files and folders
                            .start();
                }
            });
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

                startActivityForResult(data, requestCode);

            if (requestCode == 1000 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                String filePath = data.getStringExtra(FilePickerActivity.RESULT_FILE_PATH);
                // Do anything with file
                tvaf.setText(filePath);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 1001: {
                if(grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Permission not granted!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    isRemoving();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have error inside `onActivityResult`,
Remove `startActivityForResult(data, requestCode);`

The working function should look like:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 1000 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String filePath = data.getStringExtra(FilePickerActivity.RESULT_FILE_PATH);
            // Do anything with file
            tvaf.setText(filePath);
    }
}
```

When using this library inside fragment you need

```
.withSupportFragment(this)
```

Also, I would recommend checking for permissions on buttonClick instead onCreateView.

The fully functional code would look like:

```
public class AttachmentsFragment extends Fragment {


public static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE = 0;
public static final int FILE_PICKER_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

public AttachmentsFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_attachments, container, false);

    Button pickButton = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_choose_files);
    pickButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            checkPermissionsAndOpenFilePicker();
        }
    });

    return view;
}

private void checkPermissionsAndOpenFilePicker() {
    String permission = Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(), permission)) {
            showError();
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{permission}, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    } else {
        openFilePicker();
    }
}

private void openFilePicker() {
    new MaterialFilePicker()
            .withSupportFragment(this)
            .withRequestCode(FILE_PICKER_REQUEST_CODE)
            .withHiddenFiles(true)
            .withTitle("Sample title")
            .start();
}

private void showError() {
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Allow external storage reading", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       @NonNull String permissions[], @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                openFilePicker();
            } else {
                showError();
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == FILE_PICKER_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        String path = data.getStringExtra(FilePickerActivity.RESULT_FILE_PATH);

        if (path != null) {
            Log.d("Path (fragment): ", path);
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Picked file in fragment: " + path, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Still, no result appears in the filePath. I tried also to debug but nothing happens.

Comment: What happens when you click on the button? Does the Permission is granted? Have you add the permissions in the Manifest?

Comment: no such permission pops up on my screen upon clicking the button. I already add this code to my manifest:<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Comment: Check for my edited answer and let me know if it helps

Comment: It fixed now. you're such a great man. you saved my life this time.